# Why data-dismiss in bootstrap is not working?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

The `data-dismiss` in bootstrap is not working. It is working in another project but not in this project. Please suggest me where I am going wrong.

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {   
       @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.txtName)
       <button type="submit" id="submit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Produce Page</button>      
    } 

//My Modal

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModal" aria-hidden="true">
    ...
            <div class="modal-header">
                ...
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                    ...
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"><a href="~/MyHome/MyHome">Go to My Home</a></button>
                    </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this snippet.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous"> @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post)) { @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.txtName)
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button> }




<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        @Html.Partial("My partial View")
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Bootstrap modal with Pure Javascript

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";

  var Modal = function(el, options) {
    var self = this;

    this.el = document.querySelector(el);
    this.options = options;

    try {
      var list = document.querySelectorAll('#' + this.el.id + ' [data-dismiss="modal"]');
      for (var x = 0; x < list.length; x++) {
        list[x].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
          if (e) e.preventDefault();
          self.hide();
        });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };

  /**
   * Methods
   */
  Modal.prototype.show = function() {
    var self = this;
    // adding backdrop (transparent background) behind the modal
    if (self.options.backdrop) {
      var backdrop = document.getElementById('bs.backdrop');
      if (backdrop === null) {
        backdrop = document.createElement('div');
        backdrop.id = "bs.backdrop";
        backdrop.className = "modal-backdrop fade in";
        document.body.appendChild(backdrop);
      }
    }

    // show modal
    this.el.classList.add('in');
    this.el.style.display = 'block';
    document.body.style.paddingRight = '13px';
    document.body.classList.add('modal-open');
  };

  Modal.prototype.hide = function() {
    var self = this;
    // hide modal
    this.el.classList.remove('in');
    this.el.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.style = '';
    document.body.classList.remove('modal-open');

    // removing backdrop
    if (self.options.backdrop) {
      var backdrop = document.getElementById('bs.backdrop');
      if (backdrop !== null) document.body.removeChild(backdrop);
    }
  };


  /* Event */
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var m = new Modal('#MyModal', {
      backdrop: true
    });
    document.getElementById('btn-open').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      if (e) e.preventDefault();
      m.show();
    });
  });
})();
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post)) { @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.txtName)
<a href="#" id="btn-open" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Click Me</a> }



<div id="MyModal" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not working into my system. Is there any other way to call this button using JavaScript and hide this.

Comment: Edited the answer with javascript part as well

Comment: Still not working. When I click on close, nothing happens.

Comment: Check whether you have similar variables attached to other functions. Because it works well in the snippet. Or check the bootstrap version

Comment: This is not working. I do not why this is happening.I checked in other functions but not identical variable.

Comment: Try running this in an independent project, if it works, that means, some where else is the issue. If still the above snippet not works, that means something wrong in the above code. Hope you check bootstrap versions. And it only doesn't work when your closing it right? Modal opens at first?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163760/discussion-between-raj-and-lakindu-gunasekara).